# Is there a way to read an Array of Values stored in a XML into a typed ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I just started working with Android Studio and Java overall. I want to read in a file (can be any file format) that stores an array of pairs of String + long. I then want to type that array into a class (assuming that'll just be a simple for loop constructing the elements by what I've read from the XML) - QUestion is more about reading the data in.

I have fiddled around alot with the files in res/values/ but haven't found a way to assign two values to one item. If I could call xml[0].string and xml[0].long, that'd be by far enough for what I'm intending to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set two array in the resources to make one at the end

*res/values/arrays.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer-array name="integer_array">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </integer-array>
    <string-array name="string_array">
        <item>string 1</item>
        <item>string 2</item>
        <item>string 3</item>
        <item>string 4</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

*in your class*

```
Resources res = getResources();
int[] ints = res.getIntArray(R.array.integer_array);
String[] strings = res.getStringArray(R.array.string_array);

//add them to your object array
ArrayList<YourObject> list = new ArrayList();

int i = 0;
while(i < ints.length){
    //make sure the two lists are the same size
    list.add(new YourObject(ints[i], strings[i]));
    i++;
}
```

I'm not sure if you can get `long` items with this but integer should do the job

Comment: This works well. I can get around not using long for now, i guess.

Another question to add up on this - visualizing my idea a bit.

I intend to create a default set of Data the user can use to "test" the App (also for me test it in development, but I wanted something I can actually use in Production later on.. not a half assed person). The user can add other values as well later on, how would I store/read that? Some keywords should be enough to help get some Information on the topic.

Comment: Well you could setup a sqlite database and make calls to this, it is more flexible than this. Setting up value in xml file is good for simple things like values for a spinner (if the user have to choose between a fixed amout of item in a dropdown list for instance) but to store user data (or other things), you should go for a database (sqlite is built in, but their are other options aswell)

Comment: And you can store `long` in a database

Answer (score 0):

Try This, Example:  **put this in arrays.xml in rec/values/arrays.xml**

```
<string-array name="array_gender">
        <item>Select Gender</item>
        <item>Male</item>
        <item>Female</item>
    </string-array>
```

Usage

```
List<String> myArrayList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_gender));
```

Comment: How would the corresponding XML be located and looking? I'm pretty confused by how most of this handles.. or rather spoiled by .json in js i guess.